# Unresolved External Symbol Error When Using cvEigenDecomposition and Others

Tags: c, opencv

I am new to learning openCV and was trying to reproduce an online example "face recognition" program here:  http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/index.html.
I am however getting an "unresolved external symbol" error for few functions:

```
cvEigenDecomposite
cvCalcEigenObjects
indNearestNeighbor(float *)    // functions defined locally by the user
loadTrainingData(struct CvMat *)  // functions defined locally by the user
```

The "unresolved external symbol" would show up when I mess up the linker. The weird thing, it worked just fine for other examples I have done so far on other websites. My reasoning is that the first two functions `cvEigenDecomposite` and `cvCalcEigenObjects`  require extra .lib object that I haven't linked to and the other two functions depend on the first two. So my question is whether those functions  require extra .lib objects to be linked to?
here is the list of the .lib objects I currently link to:

```
opencv_core231d.lib
opencv_highgui231d.lib
opencv_imgproc231d.lib
opencv_features2d231d.lib
opencv_calib3d231d.lib
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

ERRORS:

1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvEigenDecomposite referenced in function "void __cdecl learn(void)" (?learn@@YAXXZ)

1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvCalcEigenObjects referenced in function "void __cdecl doPCA(void)" (?doPCA@@YAXXZ)

1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl findNearestNeighbor(float *)" (?findNearestNeighbor@@YAHPAM@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl recognize(void)" (?recognize@@YAXXZ)

1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl loadTrainingData(struct CvMat * *)" (?loadTrainingData@@YAHPAPAUCvMat@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl recognize(void)" (?recognize@@YAXXZ)

1>C:\Users\Lyukshins\Dropbox\Programming\OpenCV2\Face Recognition\Debug\Face Recognition.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

DEPENDENCIES:

C:\opencv\build\include

C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2

C:\opencv\build\include\opencv

INCLUDED DIRECTORIES:

C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib

C:\opencv\build\include

Comment: Can you paste the full linker command and errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvEigenDecomposite` and `cvCalcEigenObjects` are located in **opencv_legacy231d.lib**

The other 2 functions, as you said, are local functions. So they must be declared in the code before the functions that call them.